# Using MDX with NextJS 13 returning useContext error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, mdxjs

I'm trying to use mdx files in Next.js 13. I've already done all the necessary configuration in next.config and created the file.
Inside the app folder, I have > docs > components > accordion > page.mdx

The page file only renders a title like "# Title". When I navigate to this URL, I get the following error:

node_modules/@mdx-js/react/lib/index.js (34:26) @ React error - createContext only works in Client Components. Add the "use client" directive at the top of the file to use it. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/context-in-server-component

How could I fix this?

my next.config.js

```
const withMDX = require('@next/mdx')({
  extension: /\.mdx?$/,
  options: {
    remarkPlugins: [],
    rehypePlugins: [],
  },
})

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  pageExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'md', 'mdx'],
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
}

module.exports = withMDX(nextConfig)
```

Comment: Where are you using mdx in the code?

Comment: @YoussoufOumar like I said, inside app > docs > components > accordion > page.mdx
The content of the file is just a title.
# Title

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the root of your project, make sure to add the file mdx-components.tsx:

```js
import type { MDXComponents } from "mdx/types";

// This file is required to use MDX in `app` directory.
export function useMDXComponents(components: MDXComponents): MDXComponents {
  return {
    // Allows customizing built-in components, e.g. to add styling.
    // h1: ({ children }) => <h1 style={{ fontSize: "100px" }}>{children}</h1>,
    ...components,
  };
}
```

Also, my next.config.js looks like this (same as provided example bellow), but I've tried with yours and it's also working fine:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
};

const withMDX = require("@next/mdx")();
module.exports = withMDX(nextConfig);
```

Also, you can take a look at this example: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/app-dir-mdx