# MDX breaks with "use client" in Next app router

Tags: javascript, next.js, mdxjs

I've configured MDX with Next.js 14, but upon navigating to the mdx page, it throws the error:

`Error: createContext only works in Client Components. Add the "use client" directive at the top of the file to use it.`

My mdx-components.tsx is located at the root of the `app` directory.
(`app/mdx-components.tsx`)

Here's my `next.config.mjs`:

```js
import nextMDX from "@next/mdx";

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const nextConfig = {
  env: {
    AIRTABLE_API_KEY: process.env.AIRTABLE_API_KEY,
  },
  pageExtensions: ["js", "jsx", "mdx", "ts", "tsx"],
};

const withMDX = nextMDX({
  options: {
    remarkPlugins: [],
    rehypePlugins: [],
  },
});

export default withMDX(nextConfig);
```

And here's `mdx-components.tsx`:

```js
import type { MDXComponents } from "mdx/types";

export function useMDXComponents(components: MDXComponents): MDXComponents {
  return {
    ...components,
  };
}
```

The page I'm trying to render is located at `app/work/page.mdx`

`page.mdx` simply contains the title in markdown format.

Tried Solutions:

- Configured from : [Official Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/mdx)
- [This](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/57538) GH issues (Issue persists. Most of them were suggesting to add `mdx-components.tsx` at root directory which I already have)
- [Using MDX with NextJS 13 returning useContext error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75915454/13571736)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around to deal this. All you need to have is create a `page.jsx` file or .tsx it's upto you. There you can import this mdx file with "use client" directive.

```
"use client";
import AnyNameOfYourChoice from "./page.mdx";

export default function Page() {
  return <AnyNameOfYourChoice />;
}
```

for more see this https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/50897#discussioncomment-6122518